# SQL Server session State Management in ASP.Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have implemented SQL Server session state in my ASP.NET website using the solution described in this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/configure-sql-store-session-state). The solution works correctly, but now I want to modify it so that the connection string is stored in an environmental variable instead of being directly specified in the web.config file. The reason for this is that I want to enhance the security of the connection string. However, I do not have write permissions to the web.config file.

I have researched various approaches to configure the SQL Server session state and connection string using environmental variables, but I haven't found a suitable solution yet. Can someone provide guidance or share their solution for configuring SQL Server session state and setting the connection string using environmental variables without requiring write permissions to the web.config file?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ASP.NET wasn’t designed to allow that.

Comment: Do you know if we have any work around to implement Session state recording in the SQL Database? I am currently have Session State implemented in most of the codes but it is currently InProc.

Comment: You can easy encrypt the strings in web config. I mean, how does the authentication database or most other settings work then? IIS reads that information from web.config to run correctly. Having web config read only is good idea, but I fail to EVER see the need to modify the web config anyway beyond "at deploy time". I would encrypt the connection strings, but for things like authentication database, and things like asp.net session database? Yes, they quite much have to be placed in web.config. (read only don't change that issue).